# Receive dynamic input (name[]) in Google App Engine

Tags: python, forms, google-app-engine

How to access (in Google App Engine) the input that is created dynamically:

```
<form action="/add" method="post">
<input type="text" name="line[]">
<input type="text" name="line[]">
<input type=submit">
```

I tried to access it via:

```
    for i in self.request.get('line[]'):
       self.response.out.write(i)
    #this only gives first value
```

or

```
    self.response.out.write(self.request.get('line[]')[1])
    #this gives index out of range.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i got it, i supposed to use  `self.request.get_all('line[]')`

Comment: Python is not PHP. There's no need for the `[]` in the fieldname.